# What is the proper way to override a django view

Tags: django, authentication, view

Trying to implement `authentication` for a django app. 
I want to override some django `auth` views.

So should i edit the file directly in `django.contrib.auth.views` or is there a better method to override it ?

Do ask, if the question needs more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't** edit the file directly. please.

You need customize the authentication..
Read this [Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/), can be helpful.

Comment: but in the reference link you provided, it does not mention, how to over ride a django view. ???????

Comment: for eg: currently, a successful login redirects to `/accounts/profile`, but i want to change it to `/x/xx`. Do give a code example on how to do the same, without editing the original file

Comment: @dreamer That's the [`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) setting.